# Can Ubuntu dock be at the bottom when screen is rotated?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, display-rotation

I have a touchy laptop, and with Ubuntu 18, the screen rotates with it.
Superb. However, normally the dock is at the left (which for screen real estate is optimal), but when the screen is in portrait mode, it ought to be at the bottom.

Is this possible at all, and if so, how?

Comment: you can configure where you want.

Comment: ok that comes very close to what i want indeed. just that it appears at the top. im sure if you replace the the 'top' parameter by the correct one ('bottom' doesnt work), then itd be exactly how it should be. but definitely in the right direction. should be standard though, or at least have the option for it.

Comment: CORRECTION: it DOES work. i failed to see the third 'top' label to replace. all three labels are now replaced and it works great. much appreciated for the help